# Calculate the distance matrix using a custom Mahalanobis distance

Tags: r, math, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I need to calculate the Mahalanobis distance according to a known formula:

[image]

I did the following: I have a function that uses this formula:

```
overall_dist<-function(a, b, c, p, W){
  if(c=="Mahalanobis dist"){
    dist <- t(a-b)
    print(dist)
    dist <- dist%*%W
    print(dist)
    dist <- sqrt(dist%*%(a-b))
    print(dist)
    #dist <- dist * (a-b)
    #dist
    #dist <- sqrt(dist*(a-b))
  }
  return(dist)
}
```

The matrix of coefficients is:

```
w1<-c(1,0)
w2<-c(0,1)
W<-rbind(w1,w2,w3)
```

Then there is another function that calculates the distance matrix:

```
X<-matrix(c(-1,1,2,-1,2,3,1,2,3,0), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
X

make_dm<-function(mat){
matrix_dist<-matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = nrow(mat))
  for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    for (j in 1:(i-1)){
      matrix_dist[i,j] <- overall_dist(mat[i,], mat[j,], c="Mahalanobis dist", p, W)
      matrix_dist[j,i] <- matrix_dist[i,j]
    }
  }
return(matrix_dist)
}
make_dm(X)
```

For example if I have 2 vectors:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(4,6,1)
```

then distance considers correctly, and when I use function for calculation of a distance matrix such error turns out here.

[image]

why do I get zeros? what could be the problem with the error and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to provide reproducible data for testing your functions. Your first function includes an argument for `c` that is never used. Your object `W` includes a variable `w3` that is not defined. It is not clear if `W` is the covariance matrix or the inverse of the covariance matrix as required in the equation you provided. Is there some reason you cannot just use the function `D2.dist` in the package `biotools`?

Comment: @dcarlson, yeah I need to create my own custom function, about w3 it shouldn't be there, I forgot to delete it. If I use inverse matix I have the same problem.

Comment: @dcarlson can you propose something with my code?